# reflection LIE groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

There is a nice theory of discrete reflection groups and discrete
generalized reflection groups. What about compact Lie groups
(subgroups of U(n) ) that are generated by reflections ( or generalized reflections)?
the unitary and orthogonal groups are examples. Have such groups been studied/ classified?
References?

Comment: Two trivial remarks: 1. If the subgroup G is simple as an abstract group, this is just the question on whether G contains any (complex) reflections at all. 2. One then asks which irreducible representations $G\to U(n)$ sends any involution to a reflection. The latter question probably has the answer "hardly any", but making this precise would require doing some computations.

Comment: Indeed, if we compose $G \to U(V) \to U(V \otimes {\mathbb C}^2)$ then $G$ is not such a group. Hi Harm, welcome to MO!

Comment: I don't have a useful answer to your question, but I vaguely recall at least one conference talk in which $O(n)$ was compared, with quite some success, to a finite reflection group, so this question is not entirely out of left field.

Comment: There are no simple reflection Lie groups. If $G$ is a simple reflection Lie group, then it is generated by commutators and commutators lie in $SU(n)$. So G is contained in $SU(n)$ but 
$SU(n)$ does not contain any (generalized) reflections.
But perhaps one may consider the case for which $G/[G,G]$ is finite.
